# CPU efficient way to flash the screen a certain color in Pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am working on a game using Python and Pygame and I want to flash the screen red when the player is hit. I wish for the red to fade in and out again. I used something along the lines of the following.

somewhere when the program initializes:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
red = pygame.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
red.fill((255,0,0))
bleeding = False
going_back = False
```

somewhere in the main loop:

```
if bleeding:
    if not going_back:
        alpha += 2
    else:
        alpha -= 2
    red.set_alpha(alpha)
    screen.blit(red, (0,0))
    if alpha >= 50:
        going_back = True
    if alpha == 0 and going_back:
        bleeding = False
        going_back = False
```

when the player gets hit I just say:

```
bleeding = True
```

This works, however, when it happens I get a major FPS drop for the second or so that it happens. I know there must be a more efficient way to create this effect, however I am lost as to how. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: nice question.  I don't think there is faster way to achieve this. If the line "red.set_alpha(alpha)" affects fps much probably can make the effect less smoother (changes the alpha not every cycle or make several surfaces with predefined alpha). But I doubt it will help much if at all. So test if you comment out this line, does it makes much FPS difference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your screen is named `screen`, just do this

```
bleedout_timer = 0


# In your loop
if bleeding:
    screen.fill((255, 0, 0)) # R, G, B
    bleedout_timer += 1

else: # Not bleeding
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) # White


# Reset the timer after the player has bleeded out.
if bleedout_timer > 50: # Experiment with this time length
        bleeding = False # Stop red screen
        bleedout_timer = 0 # Reset
```

You can remove all the other things that do not affect `bleeding`, which henceforth will be the only needed variable.

This should be the most CPU efficient manner of doing this, as it uses the least possible stuff.

Comment: The effect I'm going for is more that the red fades in and fades out.